# PHP - Formatting a Date

Tags: php, string, date, compare, seconds

I have a date stored into a string variable as such: `Sun Jun 02 08:54:12 EDT 2013`. How can I convert this into a date variable to compare the time difference between the current date and the date provided. Thanks!

Comment: where are you getting the dates from, a database, text string, csv file? Can you show us the code you have tried so far? Thanks

Comment: I think you're simply looking for the function strtotime() [http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php]

Comment: I have already obtained the date I want to compare with and have stored it into a string. I'm wondering what to do from here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to compare the current date with the timestring. Once you have the `DateTime` objects you can easily get the difference using the method [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). It will return a [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object that can be printed using it's [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method.

```
$dt = new DateTime('Sun Jun 02 08:54:12');
$now = new DateTime();

if($now > $dt) {
    $difference = $now->diff($dt);
    echo $difference->format('The time is %H hours %I minutes %S seconds in the past');
} else if ($now < $dt) {
    $difference = $dt->diff($now);
    echo $difference->format('The time is %H hours %I minutes %S seconds in the future');
} else {
    echo 'the time is now';
}
```

**Note**: Of course you'll have to extend the output in a way that it displays the difference in years, months and days additionally. I didn't that in the example, because I'm lazy ... aehhmm because the string would get too long for the example ... ;)